# Plotting rolling 12 month average and quarterly average

Tags: charts, linebreaks

I have the below graph that shows monthly availability, quarterly average of the availability and 12 month rolling average. Here, I dont want to quarterly average line graph to be continuous. I would like to see a break between two quarters For example, the quarterly average should stop at Jun 17 and start again at Jul 17. The line connecting them should break. how do i achieve this?

[image]

Comment: It would help to let us know what software you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Plot the average line as four different series.

[image]